# TwilioRestClient SendMessage not resolving

Tags: c#, twilio

I've updated my Twilio library to latest and now `SendMessage` no longer resolves.

> client.SendMessage("YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER", "YOUR_NUMBER", "Ahoy from Twilio!");

How do I send a text with the current C# Twilio libarary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sounds like you've updated from version 4 to version 5 of the [Twilio C# library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp). This was an update with breaking changes and there is a full [upgrade document available here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x).

For [sending messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) you need to update to use the new [`MessageResource`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x#resource-classes). Here's an example:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Example
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "your_account_sid";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var to = new PhoneNumber("+15017250604");
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            to,
            from: new PhoneNumber("+15558675309"),
            body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?");
        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
   }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.